# Who is the artist behind the US box art for the first Mega Man?

Tags: mega-man

I've tried looking around but I have failed miserably to find it myself. **Who is the artist behind the box art for the US release of the first [Mega Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_Man_%28video_game%29)?**

[image: Bad Box megaman]

Box art taken from [Megaman wikia](http://megaman.wikia.com/wiki/Bad_Box_Art_Mega_Man).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While we do not have the name, we do know who the person was and why it turned out like it did. Here's from an interview with the American MM team:

*Quote:*

> The president of Capcom US said to his marketing guy: "We need a
> cover done tomorrow".
> He went out and got a friend of his to do it in like 6 hours.

Source (timestamp 05:33):

On the home page of Marc Ericson (https://www.retrogameart.com), who created the cover for Mega Man 2, he states that:

> "The infamous MegaMan (which which was drawn and painted overnight due
> to a rush schedule, by an ***art student friend [of] Keiji Inafune***, The
> producer), showing a horrible rendition of a strangely dancing MegaMan
> character, in a billowing yellow and blue Hammer-Time style jump suit,
> WAVING A PISTOL"

Comment: Oh gosh, it was worth waiting 4 and a half year for this answer. Too bad it's not better sourced in the video itself but I think that's the best we'll get.

Comment: Thanks, not quite the epitome answer but better than nothing I hope. The name may surface one day (unless the author is hiding in shame : P)